# Email servers for windows servers?

Tags: mail-server

currently I have only seen products from smartertools for email servers that run on windows boxes.

what are you guys running?  Is there any other options?

It gets expensive when you have multiple servers requiring their software.

Answer (score 2):

Imail Server works well for small organizations.
http://www.imailserver.com/

Answer (score 1):

We use [Kerio Email Server](http://www.kerio.com/kms_home.html). It works well for us.

Answer (score 1):

hMailServer.  Free and open source.

http://www.hmailserver.com

Answer (score 1):

I have been running SmarterMail for a long time and have been very happy with its performance and function.